# Are initial online video interviews pass fail, or are they evaluated in a way that causes them to matter later in the interview process?

Tags: interviewing

It occurs to me that I probably did really well on one of my later interviews but probably did only good enough on my initial video interview.

Comment: All interview stages are pass/fail as far as the applicant is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

> Are initial online video interviews pass fail, or are they evaluated
>   in a way that causes them to matter later in the interview process?

Every company handles interviews differently. Some might have pass/fail video interviews. Many don't.

The fact that you had interviews after your initial video interview probably means that it wasn't pass/fail.

But the only ones who could provide a full answer work at the interviewing company.